# File has different owner if examined using `sudo`

Tags: terminal, finder, permission, sudo

I have some files backed up on an external HD, and according to Finder they're all owned by my standard user account. According to Terminal, however, they're owned "unknown" if I look at them using `sudo`. If I don't use `sudo` they agree with Finder. I still seem to have normal access to them, but can anyone tell me what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These files are owned by UID 99, which is the unknown user.  These files were, perhaps, initially created by an account that is no longer on the system, or a "different version of yourself" that was migrated from a previous version of the OS, etc.  To avoid confusion, when a normal user inspects these files, they appear to belong to whoever is viewing them.  When root inspects them (via `sudo`, for example), their actual owner is shown.

The following describes this in greater detail:

http://googlemac.blogspot.com/2007/03/user-99-unknown.html